# At Flutter When the new category button is clicked, I want it to first get a category name and then create a new button with that name

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm very new to Flutter and I'm trying to learn. When the new category button is clicked, I want it to first get a category name and then create a new button with that name. In short, .
[I want the user to create and name the categories as in the picture][1]

````
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVlWm.png

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
````

//widget

```
class Categoriespage extends StatefulWidget {
const Categoriespage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<Categoriespage> createState() => _CategoriespageState();
}

class _CategoriespageState extends State<Categoriespage> {
TextEditingController CategoryNameController = 
TextEditingController();
var category;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'Kategoriler',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
```

//body container

```
  body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [

        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
```

//

```
        RaisedButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: 
   BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[ //textfield and button
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 
          10, 0),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: CategoryNameController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Kategori Adı',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

//Onpressed will be filled later

````
                      Container(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed:() {},
                          child: const Text('Oluştur'),) ,

                      ),


                    ],
                  );
                });
          },

          padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 15, bottom: 
          15),
          color: Colors.pink,
          child: Text(
            '+ Kategori Ekle',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                letterSpacing: 0.6),
          ),
        ),
        ],
        ),
        ),
        );
        }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Please also add your solution code and people will point out if it is wrong or right. Don't ask for solution only.

Comment: you can create button inside visibility and get name of button from category

Answer (score 0):

Then you can use a [ModalBottomSheet](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/modal-bottom-sheet-in-flutter-dae05debbed2) or a   [AlertDialog](https://medium.com/multiverse-software/alert-dialog-and-confirmation-dialog-in-flutter-8d8c160f4095) .
You can a make input fields inside these widgets and if the proper values are provided then you can create your desired widget for the list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank  you  I use modalBottomSheet